# I just imported some shapefiles to a PostGIS database, where can I find the files in my drive?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, spatial-database

When I installed PostGIS, the default directory for all data is `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data` but I can't find any folder that seems to be related to the database (named 'discover') that I made.
[image]

Comment: [PostGreSQL: Database Physical Storage](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/storage-file-layout.html)

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL uses an internal, efficient storage for the data. There are no human-readable or human-identifiable files in your filesystem. Your imported geo data is now accessible via SQL only.